# C# TimeSpan with Exclusions

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, time, timespan

I know this is probably not possible but off hand does anyone know if there are any shortcuts or mechanisms within .NET to allow me to do this.

I have a 'Diary'

9AM - 5PM

Inside this diary I have events or 'Appointments'

10AM - 12PM - Appointment 1
1PM - 1:30PM - Appointment 2

What I am asking for is there a tool that I can invert the diary to give me free spaces outside of these Appointments.

E.g. It would return me a list of

9AM - 10AM
12PM - 1PM
1:30PM - 5PM

So that I can then use within my program.

Any Ideas?

Comment: you have "Diary" object or list or db table? . Post some more information....

Comment: What does TimeSpan have to do with this? What have you tried already and in what way were the results unsatisfactory? Finding the blocks of free time in a given interval given a list of non-free time intervals shouldn't be hard; if you can live with sometimes suboptimal performance it should even be easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check this CodeProject article: [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET), specifically the `TimeGapCalculator` example.

Comment: Wow, this site is competitive. I bow to your quick fingers.

Comment: @Oliver: well, yeah it's those [fake internet points people are willing to do anything for](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/). And since I used that library some time ago I remembered it might be helpful.

Comment: The functionality TheMonkeyMan is looking for is in `TimeGapCalculator` Edit: oh really.. you're fast :P

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is! I highly suggest using this free library from the CodeProject called [TimePeriod](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET).

This library will handle

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem that hard to implement yourself:

- Sort the diary appointments by start date.
- One free period from start diary > first appointment
- One free period from last appointment > end diary
- Iterate the appointments and each period in between is a free period

Comment: Some consideration should be taken for cases where multiple appointments have the same start time. For example, it would be wise to sort them by their start time, *then by* their end time, so that the latter appointment always yields a smaller gap when iterating.

Comment: I was assuming that you do not allow overlaps in your appointments. It does get more complicated if you do.